# databinding without FormView?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, data-binding, wizard

I have an ASP.NET page with a Wizard control containing several steps and about 80 form fields. The data is collected and inserted to a database from the code behind page. I need to set this form up so you can not only insert, but edit a record as well. So I want to databind the fields.  I'd rather not use a FormView because then I would have to revise my existing code, since you can't access controls inside a FormView directly. Is there a way to databind the fields without using a FormView? I'm new at this by the way so sorry if the answer should be obvious.

Answer (score 0):

A wizard is just a UI control with many steps in it. You can use it to insert, edit, delete or anything else you can think of. You can have an INSERT wizard and an EDIT wizard. The difference would be that there would be two of them and that the code behind for each one (presumably on the CompletedStep) would have slightly different code to persist the data. The insert wizard would call an insert database query and the edit one would call an update query.

That being said, you *can* access the control inside a `FormView`, I'm not sure why you said that you can't access controls indie a FormView. You can. See [Using FindControl: Accessing Controls in a Formview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603947/using-findcontrol-accessing-controls-in-a-formview).

You could even put the two wizards inside the two states of the formview - `InsertTemplate` and `EditTemplate` but thats getting a little crazy :)

Comment: Well I know you can access them in the FormView, but just not directly, as in, I'd have to go into my code behind, which is over 700 lines of code, and change each place where I access a control. So is there a way to do this without two wizards? Because the form is pretty huge and complex, and I'd rather just have one form that can be used for both inserting and updating, rather than have two versions of the exact same thing.